# Wipe AsyncStorage in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, asyncstorage

I notice that I am wasting a certain amount of time debugging **redux** actions that I am persisting to `AsyncStorage` in **react-native** thanks to [redux-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist). Sometimes I'd just like to wipe AsyncStorage to save some development time and try with fresh data.

EDIT: Best case the solution should work on simulators and real devices, iOS and Android. Maybe there are different work arounds for different platforms.

Thanks

Comment: you can try react-native-dev-button. Small addition which does exactly what you need. i actually added the purge() from redux-persist to the clearActions and used it whenever i needed it.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Try using [clear()](https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/api/#clear) function which erases all `AsyncStorage` for all clients, libraries, etc

Comment: It would require a really small implementation, sounds good. Do you have a global helper method under `window` object or something similar?

Comment: @jsdario It's $reactNative in debugger mode. Please see my answer.

Comment: The above embedded is not working! So use this updated link for API Documentation for [clear()](https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/api#clear) function

Answer (score 35):

```
clearAsyncStorage = async() => {
    AsyncStorage.clear();
}
```

This function can be applied anywhere on the code base to clear `AsyncStorage`. For example, here is how it can be called on a `<Button>` component.

```
<Button onPress={this.clearAsyncStorage}>
  <Text>Clear Async Storage</Text>
</Button>
```

Comment: Code only answers are generally discouraged on Stack Overflow as they aren't usually very clear. Please consider updating this answer with a brief description of what you're doing, how it works, and a link to relevant documentation.

Answer (score 19):

You can clear AsyncStorage easily without touching your source code. Using [react native debugger](https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger); and in the devtools console type

```js
$reactNative.AsyncStorage.clear();
```

or to call it in RN's normal debugger with `clear()` you can put this in...

```js
if (__DEV__) {
   global.clear = () => {
     AsyncStorage.clear().then(() => console.log('Cleared'))
   }
}
```

Comment: If you want to validate that you've cleared your key, you can run ```$reactNative.AsyncStorage.getAllKeys().then(data => console.log(data));``` to list out your keys after you run the above command form react native debugger.

Answer (score 17):

IMHO, all the answers referring to *AsyncStorage.clear()* are wrong, since, as the [documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/asyncstorage#clear) say:

> Erases all AsyncStorage for all clients, libraries, etc.  You probably
> don't want to call this; use removeItem or multiRemove to clear only
> your app's keys.

The correct answer may be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56003935/5532513):

> Here is a simple way of doing it:

```
clearAllData() {
    AsyncStorage.getAllKeys()
        .then(keys => AsyncStorage.multiRemove(keys))
        .then(() => alert('success'));
}
```

Comment: docs says `clear()`also work same `/**
     * Erases all AsyncStorage for all clients, libraries, etc. You probably don't want to call this.
     * Use removeItem or multiRemove to clear only your own keys instead.
     */
    clear(callback?: (error?: Error) => void): Promise<void>;`

Comment: I'm confused Yossi: removing _all_ the keys recursively isn't the same as clearing _all_ the AsyncStorage in practice?

Comment: As far as I understand from the documentation, clear() clears AsynStorage for all clients, while getAllKeys() gets only the app's keys. See https://reactnative.dev/docs/asyncstorage#clear

Answer (score 5):

`redux-persist` comes with a `purge()` callback. You can call that in a debug menu somewhere if you choose.

Comment: This is then a wrap of the previous answer, right? I'll check both methods and try to make a difference between both answers.

Comment: I have validated the other answer since AsyncStorage is always available through `import from 'react-native'`. It comes quite handy.

Answer (score 0):

Working with AsyncStorage threw a Reference Error on my side :

```
ReferenceError: AsyncStorage is not defined
```

I finally found in the React Native Debuguer [documentation](http://Working%20with%20AsyncStorage%20threw%20a%20Reference%20on%20my%20side%20:%20%20%20%20%20%20ReferenceError:%20AsyncStorage%20is%20not%20defined%20%20I%20finally%20found%20in%20the%20React%20Native%20Debuguer%20%5Bdocumentation%5D%5B1%5D%20tool%20this%20%20%20%20%20%20clearAllData%20=%20()%20=%3E%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20$reactNative.AsyncStorage.getAllKeys()%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.then(keys%20=%3E%20$reactNative.AsyncStorage.multiRemove(keys))%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.then(()%20=%3E%20alert(%27success%27));%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%20%5B1%5D:%20https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger/blob/master/docs/debugger-integration.md) a mention about

> $reactNative.*

(For RN >= 0.56)

Which led mean to this snippet to wipe out all of my local storage :

```
clearAllData = () => {
    $reactNative.AsyncStorage.getAllKeys()
        .then(keys => $reactNative.AsyncStorage.multiRemove(keys))
        .then(() => alert('success'));
}
```

Then just `clearAllData();`